# TVS diode selection for IR LED array

Tags: tvs

I need help in selecting the right TVS diode.  I am working on a home security system with a D-Link DCS-5222 camera.

I have built an IR LED array to provide night illumination.  The IR LED array is powered by 12VDC and uses about 1000mA.  I want to use a relay to power the IR LED array only when motion is detected.  The camera had DI/DO pins.  The user manual has some instructions about usin the DO pins with external relay.  See below.

I am seeking help in selecting the right diode and relay.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What makes you think you need a TVS diode at all? The LEDs themselves are diodes; damage from ESD isn't terribly likely.

Comment: I was just going by the instructions in the manual.  If I can safely omit the TVS, that would be nice.  Any advise   I am considering a relay with the following specs.  Any advise about that?  One (1) SRD-12VDC-SL-C 4 Relay Module Board
Features:
4-Channel, Compatible High/Low level Trigger
Coil Voltage: DC 12V
Pole Number: 4 Channel
Load: 10A, AC 250V/125V, DC 30V/28V

Comment: Well, what does it say in the manual about TVSes? We can't read it from here. If you have another question, you should post it separately.

Comment: @laserman I think TVS diode recommended as a flywheel diode for relay. Is it?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  There is no other information in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

You need a flywheel/flyback diode like simple 1N4001.